# How to block loading scripts in <head> or replace them from CDN on the fly?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, browser, head

I'm working on the extension for very slow government web-site
I want to prevent loading scripts or load it from CDN instead of the site (depends on the page)

I have 2 ideas:

1st - to block loading scripts at all, but can't find this ability in Chrome

2nd - run script to clear all `<scripts>` in `<head>`, but not sure is it enough to stop browser loading. But how to detect and run the script immediately when the browser got `<head>` like `[window|document].onloadedmetadata`?

Thank you

Comment: As for first option easy,- just open link **chrome://settings/content/javascript**. This Javascript disabling option in the client for compatibility/testing purposes was for ages already.

Comment: If the script is loaded using `src` then you can use webRequest or declarativeNetRequest API to simply redirect the URL. Otherwise, for an inline script, you can remove it using MutationObserver in a content script with ["run_at": "document_start"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) and then add a new DOM `script` pointing to the correct URL.